# How to disable take photo on file input iOS 6

Tags: ios, html, file, ios6

Is there an attribute for the input type file to turn off the native iOS 6 handling?

I'd like to disabled 'Take A Photo' functionality but leave 'Choose Image'.

[image: iOS take photo/choose existing functions]

Comment: I don't think you can...

Comment: Dat edit :} That needed to happen. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I've updated my answer to reflect what you are looking for. Sorry for the confusion. This articles deals with what I understand you are trying to accomplish:

http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/iphone-5-ios-6-html5-developers

Scroll down to the line that says:

> We can also request multiple files using the HTML5 new boolean attribute. In this case, the user can’t use the camera as a source.

Comment: Not sure why the downvote, but I'm looking for a front-end web solution. Thanks though!

Comment: Down vote? The link in my answer shows you how to not go the camera route. Are you looking for something else?

Comment: I upvoted to cancel it out, You've given me a native application example, I'm requesting a solution for native handling over a mobile website.

Comment: Hi @sangony, did you know any solution that works in iOS 9+? Your solution (with the `multiple` attribute) doesn't work for me neither. I posted a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44678685/html-input-file-on-ios-app-disable-take-photo-option

Answer (score 0):

The article in the other answer is dead so I don't know what the answer was. My app which runs in iOS WKWebView crashes when user choose "Take Photo". Adding `accept="application/octet-stream"` helps

```html
<input type="file" accept="application/octet-stream" />
```

Or in our case, the input is created dynamically by Javascript:

```js
txt.accept = mime; // mime is application/octet-stream
```

User is not presented with option menu and instead the file picker shows up immediately.