# HTML input file on iOS app, disable "take photo" option

Tags: ios, html, image-uploading, wkwebview

I want to disable the "Take Photo" option in an iOS app (WKWebView based) and force users to select photos from library or iCloud.

I can force users to use the camera by the `capture` boolean attribute:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" multiple capture>
```

But, I can't found anything similar to do exactly the opposite (disable camera). Is that possible with any other HMTL attribute or a different value for `capture`?

Similar question was asked here: [How to disable take photo on file input iOS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819845/how-to-disable-take-photo-on-file-input-ios-6), but the proposed solution:

> We can also request multiple files using the HTML5 new boolean attribute. In this case, the user can’t use the camera as a source.

doesn't work for me (I tried with iOS 9+).

Comment: Are you get any solution, Please help me.

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to do this with IOS. The best solution would be to block the photo if it was just taken. You can check the date of the photo and if it was within the last minute you know it was just taken and not uploaded. It is a bit inconvenient due to the fact that users have to upload the photo then have it blocked. There is no way to disable the camera.

Comment: do we know if this is still the case now in 2023? or did something change and is now different?