# How to make <input type=“file”> disable "take photo" option in Android and iOS

Tags: android, html, ios

I am building a HTML5 page which has an file input.

```
<input type=“file” >
```

When I tried to load the page using WebVivew in iOS or Android app project, I want to disable the "take photo" option for the input.

Are there any solutions?

Thank you all.

Also, I already tried the solution:  [How to disable take photo on file input iOS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819845/how-to-disable-take-photo-on-file-input-ios-6), but it does not work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819845/how-to-disable-take-photo-on-file-input-ios-6

Answer (score 1):

My app which runs in iOS WKWebView crashes when user choose "Take Photo". Adding `accept="application/octet-stream"` helps

```html
<input type="file" accept="application/octet-stream" />
```

Or in our case, the input is created dynamically by Javascript:

```js
txt.accept = mime; // mime is application/octet-stream
```